# How to use scoped locale + path_prefix with Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

In a Rails 3.2 app I'm using Devise with a `path_prefix` and localization with scoped routes.

```
#routes.rb
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
  scope "(:locale)", locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/  do
    devise_for :admins,  
      path_prefix: 'administration',
    end

   ...other resources
  end
end
```

While the url for all my other resources is written correctly eg `/en/resource/1` in the addressbar, Devise paths are passing the locale as a parameter `/administration/admins/registrations/login?locale=en`

How do I encourage Devise to use the format `/locale/path_prefix/route`?

Answer (score 2):

The first line should be replaced with the second line.

```
devise_for :admins, :path_prefix => "administration"

devise_for :admins, :path => "administration/admins"
```

So in your example, it would be:

```
#routes.rb
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
  scope "(:locale)", locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/  do
    devise_for :admins, :path => "administration/admins"

   ...other resources
  end
end
```

For more information on devise_for, check out this link: http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper#devise_for-instance_method